# "Musical Instrument" category for Facebook page? Can't ask questions on Facebook Help Centre

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

The reason I'm asking this here is because I can't post questions in the Facebook help section—I don't know why.

I can't find the "Musical Instrument" category in my page settings. I looked at every single one. I know it exists. See for example https://www.facebook.com/GibsonGuitar

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't have a complete answer, but I reported it to facebook and they have yet to respond.  My page (http://www.facebook.com/VoyagerSaxophones) was categorized as Music Instrument until recently but I noticed that it had changed to just 'company' at some point in the last couple weeks.  I'll update if they answer.